# MySQL Workbench error messages

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to apply a routine to a database using MYSQL workbench but I'm having a few problems.

In the first image below, you see the mysql I'm using. This mysql has worked for someone else (i.e. the author of the book I'm following), but when I enter it, there's three error warnings (the Xs in the red boxes).

The other two images below show what happens after I hit apply the first time(showing me the SQL to be applied on the database), and then the second time (producing the error message)

Can anyone see how to fix this problem?

Note, the code that's being entered is a formula to calculate distance between two points, but, as said, it's worked for the author of the book I'm using (Larry Ullman's PHP 5)

[image: code applied to workbench]
[image: sqlapply]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's to do with your DELIMITER declaration missing.

You need to add:-

`DELIMITER $$` on line 1 before your function.

Then remove the space from `END $$` so it becomes `END$$`